# How to enter fixed number of entries in Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 1,500 records on sheet1 and am trying to:

1. enter only 500 entries on sheet2,
2. if exceeds 500 entries the values must automatically jump to sheet3
3. and if sheet3 exceeds 500 entries has to move to sheet4.

All this can be done using VBA.

How can I crack this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), for some guidance on posting good quality questions (i.e., questions that are likely to get answered)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please. It's not optymalizing, but in this case it is not necessary:

```
Sub copyer()
counter = 1
For i = 1 To 500 Step 1
    Range("A" & i).copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
counter = counter + 1
Next i

counter = 1
For i = 501 To 1000 Step 1
    Range("A" & i).copy
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
counter = counter + 1
Next i

counter = 1
For i = 1000 To 1500 Step 1
    Range("A" & i).copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
counter = counter + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not good practice to provide wholescale code like this when the asker has not attempted this themself; it encourages a low bar for questions.

Comment: Of course. I agree with you. But this resolve is only answer to exactly this question.

Comment: Many things more to go, i have just asked one part of the code. Any way thanks starko. Hope this will help me